# Omnifaces validateMultiple component only takes UIInput values, any workaround for considering UIOutput too?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces

So, I have an Address to validate and it has 4 input fields and 4 output fields, basically the 4 output fields are city,state,county and municipality. There are not editable, so they will be populated by zipCode lookup only. But when I validate , I need to pass in all the values, the lookup values too.
`<o:validateMultiple>` only takes in Input Component values, so I tried to make them `h:inputText` too and then `disabled=true` since they aren't editable, but looks like `<o:validateMultiple>` ignores values of disabled input components as well. So, any alternatives?

Initially I did it bu embedding all the ids with respective bindings using `f:attributes` on the first inputText component and used JSF validator to grab getAttributes and validated that way, which worked OK, but since validateMultiple reduces lot of that, I wanted to use this , but looks like it is not straight forward.

Something like this could have helped :

```
<o:validateMultiple id="myId" components="foo bar baz" validator="#{bean.validateValues}" />
    <h:message for="myId" />
    <h:inputText id="foo" />
    <h:inputText id="bar" />
    <h:inputText id="baz" />

public boolean validateValues(FacesContext context, List<UIComponent> components, List<Object> values) {
    // ...
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<h:inputHidden>` if you need hidden inputs.

Comment: That worked, but still having UIComponent instead of only UIInput would have been helpful. Thanks a lot! Also, even though I don't specify any message attribute, it still throws the defaults, how do I suppress that ? P.S : I just started using OmniFaces, it is so helpful, really Kudos to you guys :)